# Xamarin form Keyboard overlapping Entry field

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to scroll the page when the keyboard is opened. Right now the keyboard is covering my other entry fields.
I have tried the soft input method. But it's not working in xamarin form.

What should I do?

Comment: Add scrollview in you layout.

Comment: tried that..not working

Comment: I have added code below. please see that. And don't forgot to put code in scrollview.

Comment: What is CenteredStackLayout in your accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add manually translation on entry focus. Try below code in constructor:

```
 this.entryname.Focused += (s, e) => { SetLayoutPosition(onFocus: true); };
 this.entryname.Unfocused += (s, e) => { SetLayoutPosition(onFocus: false); };
```

Then after just paste below method :

```
void SetLayoutPosition(bool onFocus)
    {
        if (onFocus)
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                this.CenteredStackLayout.TranslateTo(0, -100, 50);
            }
            else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                this.CenteredStackLayout.TranslateTo(0, -100, 50);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                this.CenteredStackLayout.TranslateTo(0, 0, 50);
            }
            else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                this.CenteredStackLayout.TranslateTo(0, 0, 50);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can change "50" to any value according to your requirement.

Comment: What is CenteredStackLayout in your answer?

Comment: It is my Root Stack Layout.

Comment: Thanks ..+1 from me

Comment: @SrustiThakkar This is my actual question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427967/how-to-prevent-editor-to-go-behind-the-keyboard-in-xamarin-forms. I came as per the suggestion of @AndroDevil. Your solution is working with `ScrollView`. I have a ChatPage which has a Grid of 2 rows. 1st row has ListView and 2nd row has Editor & Send button. If I use `ScrollView`, my editor goes below the screen on loading. I need to drag it up to view the editor everytime. Can you please suggest how to overcome it?