# How to prevent Editor to go behind the keyboard in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Chat app. Currently, there is an Entry control for add chat text. Now I want to provide multiline Entry, same like Whatsapp.

- If user type more than one line, it should automatic wrap the text to next line.
- If user click on Nextline button in mobile keyboard, it should go to next line.
- Height of Entry should be automatically increase upto 3 line and it should also decrease if user remove text.

To do that I have tried to replace Entry with Editor and implement following functionality.

1- Put an Editor in place of Entry.
2- Implement a functionality that keep keyboard open until user click on Message list screen or back button.

Now I am trying to implement auto height functioanlity but when user try to type, Editor goes behind the keyboard. Can anybody please suggest me how to keep Editor open and auto size?

Current code:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="MessageControls" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="2" Padding="5"
 Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <local:ChatEditorWithPlaceholder  x:Name="txtMessage" Grid.Column="0"  TextChanged="EnableSend" Text="{Binding OutGoingText}"/>
    <Frame x:Name="SendButton" Grid.Column="1" Margin= "0" Padding="0" HasShadow="false" HeightRequest="25"
BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SendMessage_Click" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <Label Text="Send" x:Name="sendButton" TextColor="#1f88b7" HeightRequest="20"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

### Editor

```
public class ChatEditorWithPlaceholder : Editor
{
    public ChatEditorWithPlaceholder()
    {
        this.TextChanged += (sender, e) => { this.InvalidateMeasure(); };
    }
}
```

### Editor Renderer:

```
public class ChatEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }
}

protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if(Control != null) {
        Control.ScrollEnabled = false;
    }
    var element = this.Element as ChatEditorWithPlaceholder;

    Control.InputAccessoryView = null;
    Control.ShouldEndEditing += DisableHidingKeyboard;

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ConversationPage>(this, "FocusKeyboardStatus", (sender) =>
    {

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.ShouldEndEditing += EnableHidingKeyboard;
        }

        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<ConversationPage>(this, "FocusKeyboardStatus");
    });
}
private bool DisableHidingKeyboard(UITextView textView)
{
    return false;
}

private bool EnableHidingKeyboard(UITextView textView)
{
    return true;
}
```

Screenshots:
[image]

Comment: Editor control supports Placeholder without custom renderers. Also, it has a property AutoSizes that achieve multiline automatically when a user types more than one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this renderer for ios.

```
using System;  
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;   

[assembly:ExportRenderer( typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.iOS
{
    public class CustomEditorRenderer: EditorRenderer
    {
        public ChatEntryRenderer()
        {   
            UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow ((sender, args) => {

                if (Element != null)
                {
                    Element.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0, args.FrameEnd.Height); //push the entry up to keyboard height when keyboard is activated
                }
            });

            UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide ((sender, args) => {

                if (Element != null)
                {
                       Element.Margin = new Thickness(0); //set the margins to zero when keyboard is dismissed
                }

            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

for android add this in MainActivity

```
 App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().
    UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Comment: I am checking this. I will let you know the result soon.

Comment: I have tested, it works for some cases but having issue in other cases. First of all I need to remove `Xam.Plugins.Forms.KeyboardOverlap` to work with your solution other wise it uses Keyboard space + Editor bottom margin(same as keyboard). Once I remove it and use your solution, it works. But there is another issue. Editor and keyboard appear correctly but Messages(ListView) goes back and it shows 3rd/4th message on the screen. Please guide.

Comment: I think you need to  manually translate the listview to above when entry focus . check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038624/xamarin-form-keyboard-overlapping-entry-field

Comment: Thanks. As per the suggestion in that answer, I have tried but `ScrollView` creates issue. That solution help in case I use `ScrollView`. In my ChatPage, I have a Grid with 2 row. 1st row having ListView and 2nd having Editor with Send button. If I implement `ScrollView`, Editor and Send button goes below the screen on loading. I need to pull it up everytime. Please advice.

Comment: No not adding scrollview.  I talked about moving the total layout to above the keyboard when editer focused.Did you see the answer of Srusti Thakkar?

Comment: Check this link too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467135/xamarin-form-move-up-view-when-keyboard-appear

Comment: Done. I took a StackLayout(Wrapper) and put a code you have given above for StackLayout. Thanks.

Comment: @NanjiMange happy coding

Answer (score 0):

For Ios there is one plugin. You can use that. The link is [Here](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap).

For Andorid you have to just set below code in MainActivity after LoadApplication(new App()) method.

```
App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android().
UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

**Updated answer for iOS :**

For IOS you can use the following custom renderer to solve the keyboard overlapping issue. And please  removed the keyboardoverlap nuget package from the project.

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using HBIClientFacingApp;
using HBIClientFacingApp.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer( typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.iOS
{
    public class CustomEditorRenderer: EditorRenderer
    {
        public ChatEntryRenderer()
        {   
            UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow ((sender, args) => {

                if (Element != null)
                {
                    Element.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0, args.FrameEnd.Height); //push the entry up to keyboard height when keyboard is activated
                }
            });

            UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide ((sender, args) => {

                if (Element != null)
                {
                       Element.Margin = new Thickness(0); //set the margins to zero when keyboard is dismissed
                }

            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Plugin has this issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zm0lMKB3wq07ve67wlcvLuNM_6Waad7R/view?usp=sharing. This is Git bug report: https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/issues/109

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/issues/109#issuecomment-288930238?

Comment: Tried and worked for Textbox. But I have an Editor with autosize using `InvalidateMeasure`. So, I have this problem: https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/issues/109#issuecomment-387714481. Please advice.

Comment: Hey! Please try this renderer one time.

Comment: There is another issue. Editor and keyboard appear correctly but Messages(ListView) goes back and it shows 3rd/4th message on the screen. Please guide. Also, you can view another answer of this question. I have processed same way before.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change this line:

```
<local:ChatEditorWithPlaceholder  x:Name="txtMessage" Grid.Column="0"  TextChanged="EnableSend" Text="{Binding OutGoingText}"/>
```

For this one:

```
<Editor x:Name="txtMessage" Grid.Column="0" AutoSize="TextChanges" TextChanged="EnableSend" Text="{Binding OutGoingText}"/>
```