# How to set editor in Xamarin Forms on iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, frontend, editor

I create  Xamarin Forms applications with the possibility of chat and i have problem with my chatPage. My code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Chat.ChatRoomPage">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition
                Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RefreshView 
                    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                    Grid.Row="0">
                <CollectionView 
                  x:Name="CollectionViewMessages" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesList}"
                  BackgroundColor="{ DynamicResource BasePageColor }">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid RowDefinitions="auto, auto">
                                <Grid IsVisible="{Binding IsOwnerMessage}">
                                    <template:ChatRightMessageItemTemplate />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid 
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  IsVisible="{Binding IsOwnerMessage, Converter={converters:BooleanConverter}}">
                                    <template:ChatLeftMessageItemTemplate />

                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </RefreshView>
            <!-- Loading gif -->
            <ActivityIndicator 
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    TranslationY="40"
                    InputTransparent="True"/>
        </Grid>
        <!--- Message Writing  -->
        <Grid 
            Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="20,10,20,10"
                ColumnSpacing="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!-- Comment -->
                <Editor
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    x:Name="entry"
                    AutoSize="TextChanges"
                    Margin="0,0,5,2"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Text="{Binding Message}"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="End"/>
                <!-- Send button -->
                <Image
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Source="SendMessageButton.png"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    WidthRequest="23"
                    HeightRequest="20"
                    Margin="0,0,0,10">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SendMessageCommand}"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

the effect of this is this:

[image]

This work well on Android but on iOS nope. After clicking something on the keyboard, the field for typing escapes below it and we cannot see what we are typing. In addition, when you switch the keyboard to emoji, its size changes and you cannot see what you are typing. The input field problem is solved if you use scrollview, but then the collectionview fills the entire screen and the input field is outside of it. How to solve this problem so that autosize and emoji work properly on iOS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin form Keyboard overlapping Entry field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038624/xamarin-form-keyboard-overlapping-entry-field). The *title* says "how to set editor" (unclear what that means), but the *description of problem* seems to be "keyboard covers entry being typed into".  Assuming that *description* is correct, there are many similar questions. Google `site:stackoverflow.com xamarin forms keyboard covers entry ios`.

Comment: This is not the solution to my problem. In my case, the problem is to change the position of the input field as you type. This is caused by the use of autosize.

Comment: *"change the position of the input field as you type."* The answer there suggests **moving the containing layout** - doesn't that do what you just said? Regardless, the google I suggest shows many more discussions - **none** of them apply to your situation?

Comment: Another possibility (don't know if it helps): Give Grid a name (`<Grid x:Name="topLayout" ...`). Then in constructor, add `entry.Focused += (s, e) => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => topLayout.ForceLayout()});` Hopefully this will tell Grid to recalculate that `Auto` row's height. The `BeginInvoke..` is to make sure Focused has completed its action, before triggering layout.

Comment: Unfortunately it also doesn't work. The problem is not scrolling the view by the user as described in your example, but changing the position of the input field automatically after pressing letters on the keyboard.

Comment: *"scrolling the view by the user"* - what do you mean? The example **programmatically shifts the entire layout up the screen by a fixed amount,** using `TranslateTo`. You pick an amount such that the input field is no longer hidden under the keyboard. The user is not involved. (I'm not sure if `TranslateTo` is available on all layouts; if not, find some alternative, such as setting a negative top margin.)